# Can someone explain and simplify projection maps and surjective homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, group-homomorphism

The question on the sheet is: Suppose we have the ring $R=\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$. Consider the projection map $p:R \to \mathbb{Z}_5$. Given by $p(a,b,c)=c$

1) show that p is a surjective homomorphism

2) Is it unital?

Can someone break down $R=\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$ looks like? Is it a set of triplets with all the possible combinations of elements in each set? Can someone break down what a projection map is to begin with? What is p, I dont understand how a mapping can be a set with $(a,b,c) = c$, what does that mean? More importantly how does one go about showing in general that something is a surjective homomorphism

Comment: Projection map is basically you just caring about one coordinate of the triple, in this case the last one, it will be surjective because for every element $a$ you want to obtain you can consider for example $(1,[1],a)$, where [1] denotes the equivalence class of 1, this prove that its surjective to prove its an homomorphism you need to check the conditions of what an homomorphism must satisfy , you think you can do that? go check them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it a set of triplets with all the possible combinations of elements in each set?

Essentially, yes. In general, for a finite product $\prod_{i=1}^n A_i$, you can envision the product as the set of elements $(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ whereby $a_i \in A_i$ for all $i$. Formally defined,

$$\prod_{i=1}^n A_i = \{ (a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n) \mid a_i \in A_i \}$$

A more familiar example of this type of product comes from the Cartesian plane (the $xy$ plane) or Cartesian $3D$ space, which are $\Bbb R^2, \Bbb R^3$ respectively. ($\Bbb R^2 = \Bbb R \times \Bbb R$, and similar for the cube.) Then, for example,

$$\Bbb R^2 = \Bbb R \times \Bbb R = \{ (x,y) \mid x,y \in \Bbb R \}$$

Of course, this definition is usually introduced with sets - as opposed to groups/rings/fields/etc. - but all that really changes is that now that Cartesian product is associated with an operation now in those cases, for example.

---

> Can someone break down what a projection map is to begin with?

This is another thing that is convenient to first think of in terms of familiar, Cartesian geometry. Consider $\Bbb R^2$ again. A projection would be defined as a function $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ which is surjective, of course, and meets all of the other associated properties.  You could define this map by the definition $(x,y) \mapsto x$. What this does, in a heuristic/informal/visual manner, is take all of the points from the $xy$ plane, and "drag" them straight up or down to the $x$ axis. You could similarly have another projection defined by $(x,y) \mapsto y$, to drag each point horizontally to the $y$ axis.

Perhaps consider instead $\Bbb R \times \Bbb Z$, which is the set of points $(x,y)$ such that $x$ is real and $y$ is an integer. This, visually, is like a bunch of horizontal stripes along the $xy$ plane, almost like the $x$ axis was duplicated infinitely many times. Each "stripe" is at some integer value $y$ and goes infinitely in any direction. In this example, we can use the same projection definitions as before. If $(x,y) \mapsto x$, then, again, all of the "stripes" are dragged down to merge with the $x$ axis. If $(x,y) \mapsto y$, then each "stripe" collapses in on itself, becoming the single integer point on the $y$ axis it stems from.

What you're beginning to deal with are these same notions, but in a more abstract, and often more difficult to visualize, environment. Essentially, a projection is a function $p : \prod A_i \to A_k$ that sends all of the elements of a product to a single set from the product, "collapsing" it in some sense, and each element of the product is sent to its "original" element from the single set. (By this I mean, for example, $(x,y) \mapsto x$ in $\Bbb R^2$ can send $(2,6)$ to $2$, the element that pair is associated with in $\Bbb R$. Of course this can often be a noninjective function since, in the same scenario, $(2,7)$ and $(2,8)$, or, really, any $(2,y)$ is sent to $2$. They're all associated with $2$ and thus sent there.)

The definition of this more general projection $p : \prod A_i \to A_k$ will typically be of the form $(a_1, \cdots, a_n) \mapsto a_k$ (where $k$ is some fixed number; $k$ might be $3$ for example, and refer to $A_3$, the third set in the product).

---

> What is p, I dont understand how a mapping can be a set with (a,b,c)=c, what does that mean?

I think Captain Lama address this point sufficiently in their post, but to be clear: projections are (typically) multi-valued functions. Remember from multivariable calculus how you might have functions like $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ or $g(x,y,z) = \sin(z)\cos(y)\tan(x)$ or whatever -- functions that took in more than one value?

It's similar here. Those functions, when framed differently, took in a "tuple" of elements. If you wanted a function that took in inputs from the $xy$ plane, you'd use $f(x,y)$ as your definition - since you're taking in a pair $(x,y)$ and using $f$ to generate an output. It was just always understood back then that $x,y,z,$ and so on, were real numbers. That is, if you have just $x,y$, you're working with $\Bbb R^2$ for instance.

Your projections also take in a tuple of elements, and output an element from a single set, so it's a similar idea. It's just now you might be dealing with tuples whose elements are not all from the same set.

---

> More importantly how does one go about showing in general that something is a surjective homomorphism

- Show it is a homomorphism
- Show, as a function, it is surjective

It's really as simple as that. Show it has the properties of a homomorphism that you expect, and show that every element of the codomain has a preimage.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a product is exactly the set of all possible tuples (here, triples since there are $3$ sets in the product).

The mapping $p$ is not "a set with $(a,b,c)=c$". You misinterpreted the sentence. When we write $p(a,b,c)=c$, it means that for any triple $(a,b,c)$ (so here $a\in \mathbb{Z}$, $b\in \mathbb{Z_3}$ and $c\in \mathbb{Z_5}$), the function $p$ sends $(a,b,c)$ to the element $c$.

To show that $p$ is surjective, take any element $x\in \mathbb{Z}_5$ and ask yourself: can I find a triple $(a,b,c)$ such that $p(a,b,c)=x$?